# Eigenvalues of a differential operator

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How would you show that if 0 is an eigenvalue for the linear differential operator L is an element of (D,D) defined as L(y)=[D-5t]y where D represents the differential operator d/dt?

Comment: what do you mean with 'Is an element of (D,D)'? What's with the $y$ only on the left-hand-side of the equation. Please clarify your question.

Comment: An element of (D,D) days that linear mapping, L, exists in the subspace of (D,D).  The y on one side of the equation was a formatting error - fixed

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the linear differential operator 
$$
L(f)=\frac{d}{dx}f-5f
$$
with domain $C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Then the eigenvector (or eigenfunction)
$$
f=e^{5x}
$$
trivially satisfies the requirement. In general you should try powers of exponential functions to solve linear differential equations (this is a special case of the method of so called [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus))). This can be found, for example in the Appendix of Stewart's calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is understandable...

Let's start with the power series as **eigenvalues** with the most important **eigenfunction** $e^{ixt}$ (which actually forms orthogonal basis of Hilbert space (see Gilbert Strang 2015). Then it is trivial to know that
\begin{align}
(-iD_t)^ne^{ixt}=x^ne^{ixt}.\label{eq:iPartialt^nEigenFun}
\end{align}
where $D_t$ is the partial differential operator.